# Can't mark a Grease Pencil Material to an asset browser?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

If I right-click the Grease Pencil Material, I can't see the menu that I make an asset.
However, Grease pencil objects can be made with assets.
Is the only way to make Grease pencil material an asset?
Is that a better way to do it?

Comment: If you have included Asset Library tags such as `asset` or `asset-browser`, I believe your question might have gotten more feedback than what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Grease Pencil Materials are different from Shader Materials. From what I've heard, grease pencil materials are not yet listed in the number of data-blocks that can be made into assets. As of Blender 4.0.2, there are still many data-blocks within Blender that are incompatible with the Asset Library.

As you have probably guessed, the current work around is to make the entire grease pencil object into an asset. Personally, if I was working on a grease pencil object, I would create a separate empty grease pencil object to turn into asset which would hold the material(s) that I want as an asset.

[image]

When calling the asset into a new scene, I can easily use the select materials by adding them as new materials and deleting the asset afterwards. If I have multiple materials that I want to add, I can simply `Join` both grease pencil objects into one.